# teamviewer is giving mainly a grey screen and not showing the remote computer's desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

teamviewer is giving mainly a grey screen and not showing the remote computer's desktop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When installing Teamviewer on the latest Mac OSX it mentions about certain permissions like "screen recorder" and "accessibility".. Those all need to be turned on.

https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/44699-remote-control-a-mac

[image]